# jQuery-based animations for FreeCodeCamp Project are slow and inconsistent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm just doing my final project for FreeCodeCamp's Front end certificate. I turned it into a fighting game, for which the button sequences initiate moves. The problem is that the animations are really buggy. Here are the details:

---Background---
-The codepen link and code are at the bottom
-When I coded it locally, everything worked great, and the player actions were were done using jquery-based animations. (I used the setTimeout(), animation(), css(), and attr() a lot to move the avatars around and switch pictures to show movement

--The problem---
-I put the code on codepen, and so I needed to host the sprite images to use them (I used dropbox). This change caused the animations to not work properly. Some of the images and sounds either load slowly or not at all. If you go to the codepen and try the buttons at the bottom you will quickly see what I mean.

---What I tried---
 -I thought that maybe this might be a problem with the app taking too long to load the assets and cache them. (because some of the animations became more fluid after I repeated them) So I added a function near the top to load the photos at the beginning 'imageInit()'. But the problem persists.

Can anyone please help me figure out what is making my jquery animations so choppy and inconsistent? Am I using the wrong techniques perhaps? Please let me know if you need any more info about this. The code is below:

Thank you!

JK

The code is here: https://codepen.io/jonnnyk20/pen/XaPqrR, and here is some code form the project:

```js
var playerSpace = $('.player-space');
var playerAvatar =  $('#player-image');

var playerImages = {
  "basic": "https://u57193820.dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/57193820/saiyan-says/images/goku/goku-basic.png",
  "attack": "https://u57193820.dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/57193820/saiyan-says/images/goku/goku-attack.png",
  "attack2": "https://u57193820.dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/57193820/saiyan-says/images/goku/goku-attack2.png",
  "attack3": "https://u57193820.dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/57193820/saiyan-says/images/goku/goku-attack3.png" }
  
  var tlp = new Audio('https://u57193820.dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/57193820/saiyan-says/sounds/misc/instant-transmission.mp3');
var hitSound = new Audio('https://u57193820.dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/57193820/saiyan-says/sounds/misc/hit.mp3');

function imageInit(obj){
  for (image in obj){
    $('<img/>')[0].src = console.log(obj[image]);
  }
}
imageInit(miscImages);
imageInit(playerImages);
imageInit(enemyImages);


function attackAnimation(){
  playerAvatar.attr("src", miscImages['blur']);
  playerAvatar.fadeOut( 100, function() {
    // Animation complete.
    playerAvatar.fadeIn( 100, function() {
    // Animation complete
       playerAvatar.attr("src", playerImages['attack']);
       enemyAvatar.attr("src", enemyImages['hurt']);
       hitSound.play();
       playerSpace.css({ left: "55%"});
       setTimeout(function(){
         playerAvatar.attr("src", miscImages['blur']);
         playerAvatar.fadeOut( 100, function() {
           playerAvatar.fadeIn( 100, function() {
             playerAvatar.attr("src", playerImages['basic']);
             enemyAvatar.attr("src", enemyImages['basic']);
             playerSpace.css({ left: "20%"});
           })
         })
       }, 200)
     });
  });
}
```

```css
.container {
  padding: 10px;
}

.row {
  margin: 0;
}

.element {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: white;
  color: #0275d8;
  border: solid 1px #0275d8;
  border-radius: 50px;
  min-width: 75px;
  min-height: 75px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding-top: 25px;
}

.progress {
  margin: 5px;
}

.healthBar {
  min-height: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  color: #023a6b;
}
.hb-label {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 5px;
    font-size: small;
}

.healthBarContainer {
background-color: white; 
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: solid 1px #3b66e6;
}

.gameInfo {
    margin: 5px;
    border: solid 1px gray;
    padding: 5px;
    /* background-color: #ececec; */
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.game-screen {
    background-color: #b2ebff;
    border: solid 1px #0275d8;
    height: 228px;
}

.game-control {
    border: solid 1px #0275d8;
    border-left: none;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
}
.button-group {
    margin: auto;
}

.game-header {
    border: solid 1px #0275d8;
    border-bottom: none;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: white;
}
.game-settings {
    border: solid 1px #0275d8;
    border-top: none;
    text-align: center;    
}

.block {
    margin-right: 40px;
}

.attack {
    margin-bottom: -20px;
}

.dodge {
    margin-top: -20px;
}

.fighter-space {
    /* border: solid 1px #3b66e6; */
    border-radius: 20px;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
}

.enemy-space {
    position: absolute;
    right: 20%;
    top: 30px;
}

.player-space {
    position: absolute;
    left: 20%;
    top: 30px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.half {
    float: left !important;
    width: 50% !important;
    z-index: 1;
}

.ki-space {
    display:none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: 30%;
    z-index: 1;
}

.lazer-space {
    position: absolute;
    top: 9px;
    left: 27%;
    display: none;
}

.test-actions {
    margin: 10px;
}

.fighter-space.km-space {
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
    left: 20%;
    display:none;
    z-index:1
}
.km-space {
    z-index: 2
}

.fighter-space.db-space {
    position: absolute;
    top: -80px;
    right: 20%;
    display: none;
}

img#db-image {
    margin-top: 40px;

}
#separate {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 10px;
  font-size: large;
  color: crimson
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="row top-row">
  <div class="col-md-12 game-header">
  Title
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row mid-row">

  <div class="col-md-7 game-screen">

      <div class="row health-bars">
        <div class="col-md-6 half">
          
          <div class="healthBarContainer">
            <div class="hb-label"> Player Health: <span id="playerHealth">0</span>  </div>
              <div class="healthBar bg-success" id="playerHealthBar" data-p="100" >
                  
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
         <div class="col-md-6 half">
            <div class="healthBarContainer">
              <div class="hb-label"> Enemy Health: <span id="enemyHealth">0</span> </div>
        
              <div class="healthBar bg-warning" id="enemyHealthBar" data-p="100" syle="min-width: 1em">
                  
              </div>
            </div>           
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 fight-ring">

          <div class="fighter-space player-space">
            <img src="https://u57193820.dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/57193820/saiyan-says/images/goku/goku-basic.png"  id="player-image" height="100" width="100">
          </div>

          <div id="projectlie">
            <div class="fighter-space ki-space">
              <img src="https://u57193820.dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/57193820/saiyan-says/images/misc/ki-blast.png"  id="ki-image" height="100" width="100">
            </div>

            <div class="fighter-space lazer-space">
              <img src="https://u57193820.dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/57193820/saiyan-says/images/misc/ki-lazer.png"  id="lazer-image" height="100" width="250">
            </div>
            
            <div class="fighter-space km-space">
              <img src="https://u57193820.dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/57193820/saiyan-says/images/misc/kamehameha1.png"  id="km-image" height="100" width="400">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="fighter-space enemy-space">
            <img src="https://u57193820.dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/57193820/saiyan-says/images/frieza/frieza-basic.png"  id="enemy-image" height="100" width="100">
          </div>
          
          <div class="fighter-space db-space">
            <img src="https://u57193820.dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/57193820/saiyan-says/images/misc/frieza-ball.png"  id="db-image" height="10" width="10">
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>


  </div>

  <div class="col-md-5 game-control">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="button-group">
        <div data-i=0 class="simon element attack">Attack</div>
      </div>
    </div>
      
    <div class="row">
      <div class="button-group">
        <div data-i=1 class="simon element block">Block</div>
        <div data-i=2 class="simon element blast">Blast</div>
      </div>
    </div>

      <div class="button-group">
      <div data-i=3 class="simon element dodge">Dodge</div>
      </div>
  





  </div>

</div>

<div class="row bottom-row">
  
  <div class="col-md-12 game-settings">
    <div class="gameInfo bg-primary" style="color: white" id="restart"> Start</div>
    <div class="gameInfo"> Mode: <span id="mode">Easy</span> </div>
    <div class="gameInfo"> Input Count: <span id="in-count">0</span> </div>
    <div class="gameInfo"> Turn: <span id="turn">Demo</span> </div> 
    <div  class="gameInfo" id="diff"> Change Mode</div>

  </div>
  <hr>
  <div id="separate">--------The Buttons Below are For Testing Purposes---------</div>
  
  <div class="col-md-12 test-actions">
    <button class="btn btn-primary test-action" data-p="0" data-a="0">Attack</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary test-action" data-p="0" data-a="1">Block</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary test-action" data-p="0" data-a="2">Blast</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary test-action" data-p="0" data-a="3">Dodge</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary test-action" data-p="0" data-a="4">Finish</button>
    <br>
    <button class="btn btn-default test-action" data-p="1" data-a="0">E. Attack</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default test-action" data-p="1" data-a="1">E. Block</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default test-action" data-p="1" data-a="2">E. Blast</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default test-action" data-p="1" data-a="3">E. Dodge</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default test-action" data-p="1" data-a="4">E. Finish</button>
   
  </div>
 <button class="btn btn-default" id="testButton"> Test Controls</button>
  






</div>





enter code here
  

</div>
```

Comment: First great work, I also started years a go with a small platform game. So I run in nearly the same situation. You should preload images and audio by simply, `new Audio()` and `new Image()` than you can preload it with `variable.src('someurl');`. At the moment your loading the images just add the second they are used. Locally this does not make much difference but if you load them externaly it does take to long.

Comment: https://www.photo-mark.com/notes/image-preloading/ This explains it quite well